# BIOS boot order priorities are fixed after installing 20.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, live-usb, bios

After installing a dual boot W10/Ubuntu I tried to add space to some of my ubuntu partitions using the same bootable USB disk.

But if I can access BIOS I cannot change anything, it displays FIXED BOOT ORDER in the BOOT menu.

I have seen this [Unable to make changes in BIOS after 17.10 installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984043/unable-to-make-changes-in-bios-after-17-10-installation/989771) but I cant get it to work
I have also tried but failed to add to grub (with grub customiser) an entry for my USB-stick.

I think I can find a workaround to upgrade a mounted partition since I already have the unallocated space I need but it bothers me not having access to my own BIOS, if I have to re-install all from scratch, right now I am screwed.

[My BIOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFjYj.jpg)

Comment: Whjat brand/model system? I think I have seen some that have a setting to lock booting for security reasons. Or may be related to UEFI Secure Boot or a allow USB boot or full USB support? Check your other tabs for some sort of related entry.

Comment: Here there are photo of all my BIOS windows https://imgur.com/a/NIndZad
As you can see 90% of the BIOS is gray instead of blue and I cannot interact with it

Comment: Maybe helpfull if you have installt in uefi mode. https://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr

Comment: Do you have the latest BIOS/UEFI installed for your model printer? If you set UEFI password never forget it or reset it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have the latest BIOS installed and cannot update it by flashing it as I am told to do on the site of the computer seller because all bios is lock, including the UEFI BIOS update tab.

Is there another way to do the update?
By the way I do have a password set but I remember it and use it each time before accessing the bios.